# how can i allow only one visitor to visit the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page call "A" Asp.Net and i want to allow only one user to access the page. If nobody accessing the page then any user are allowed to access the page
            Without using database how can i do it.
            I am trying to use page load of c# and window onbeforeunload event of javascript but didnt get it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        var hidViewstate;

        window.onload = body_Load;
        window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;

        function body_Load()
        {
            hidViewstate = document.getElementById('<%=hidViewstate.ClientID %>');
        }

        function WindowCloseHanlder()
        {
            hidViewstate.value = parseFloat(hidViewstate.value - 1);
        }

    </script>

<div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidViewstate" runat="server" />
    </div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidViewstate.Value = "1";

        if(Convert.ToInt32(hidViewstate.Value) == 1)
        {
            lblText.Text = "Welcome First User";
        }
        else
        {       
            lblText.Text = "Visiting on this page is not allowed because user is already login.";

        }

    }
```

Comment: One visitor _total_ or one session per unique login?

Comment: I have a page call "A" Asp.Net and i want to allow only one user to access the page. If nobody accessing the page then any user are allowed to access the page.

Comment: Dumb idea but you could check session count and redirect. But the very idea is weird...

Comment: It seems to go a bit against the grain of having a web application. I have to ask - what's the business case or requirement behind this?

Comment: What should happen if a user opens this webpage and then falls asleep in front of their computer/leaves it open while at work? Do you really want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is counter to how a web server should operate.  It would be interesting to know your actual problem that led you to try this.

On the technical side you could store a global variable in `Application`.  All requests share the same global object.

But if you explained to us the real problem you are trying to solve I think you would find this isn't a good approach and Im sure we could suggest a real solution.

Comment: I have to agree with the gist of the answer, the technical problem described sounds like a symptom for a bad approach to solve another problem. I am getting genuinely curious about what scenario causes such an odd requirement.

Comment: void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
  Application["InUse"]=true;
    }
    
    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
  Application["InUse"] = false;
    }

Comment: if(Convert.ToBoolean(Application["InUse"]))
  {
   lblText.Text = "Visiting on this page is not allowed because user is already login.";
  }
  else
  {
   lblText.Text = "Welcome User";
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global veriable, like static variable of a static class,

on page load you can check like

```
if(clsGlobal.userCount > 1)
{
Response.Redirect("~/anotherPage.aspx") // somewhere you want..
}
else
{
//display your welcome message
}
```